# Idiomatic Python implementation for finite sets, images, and preimages of finite functions?

Tags: python, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a finite concrete function between finite sets.  Of course, Python has sets implemented natively.

But what is the best way to implement the idea of a finite function between sets, precisely?  A wrapped dictionary?  Also, how would one implement the calculations of images and preimages? [See below.]

For images I can use map, clearly.  For preimages I can loop over the domain set and filter.  Still, I'm wondering about the more pythonic idiomatic solution.

[Wikipedia: Images (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arbitrary images from a set to another, I would use a Python dictionary. For example, f(n)=n^2 on a set of {1,2,3,4}, I can do this:

```
preimage = set([1,2,3,4])
mapping = {x: x*x for x in preimage}
image = set(mapping.values())
assert set(mapping.keys()) == preimage
function = lambda x: mapping[x] # so you can now have y = function(x)
check_image = set([function(x) for x in preimage])
assert check_image == image
```

Of course, this only works if your finite set is really finite with respect to the memory you have.

The above is the most generic case that you define the function as mapping. But in case for simpler function which  you can have a Python expression to represent it, you can skip the dictionary:

```
preimage = set([1,2,3,4])
function = lambda x: x*x
image = set([function(x) for x in preimage])
check_preimage = set([y for x in image for y in preimage if function(y)==x])
assert check_preimage == preimage
```

And if further, you have an inverse function available for the domain:

```
import math
preimage = set([1,2,3,4])
function = lambda x: x*x
inv_func = lambda x: int(math.sqrt(x))
image = set([function(x) for x in preimage])
check_preimage = set([inv_func(x) for x in image])
assert check_preimage == preimage
```

Note that, the three different code snippet above, only the first will guarantee your `function(x)` to allow only those `x` in the predefined preimage.

Speaking of the idiomic python: I don't think Python is really such a mathematical language (compare to, say, Wolfram's mathematica) so we do not have the concept of image, mapping, etc. built-in. However, you can see my code above with the list comprehension. Indeed, I just made the thing more explicit to use `set` keyword as in `set([function(x) for x in preimage])` but you can save a few keystroke with `{function(x) for x in preimage}`.

Comment: I can do the same thing for preimages, yes.  Now it's just a matter of the best way to represent a finite function as an object.

Comment: expanded the answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
def preimage(b: B, f: Dict[A, B]) -> Set[A]: 
    ''' get the preimage of one item. '''
    return set(a for a in f.keys() if f[a]==b)
```

This assumes [TypeVar and other things from pep484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

```
from typing import TypeVar, Dict, Set
A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')
```

Without type annotation it looks like this

```
def preimage(b, f): 
  ...
```

or a subset of the codomain

```
from typing import Collection
from functools import reduce

def preimage_(bs: Collection[B], f: Dict[A, B]) -> Set[A]: 
    ''' get the preimage of a collection of items '''
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), [preimage(b, f) for b in bs])
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Quinn Dougherty's answer, here's a full implementation:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import functools
from typing import (Collection, Dict, FrozenSet, Set, TypeVar)

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')


@dataclass
class FiniteFunction:
    f: Dict[A, B]
    domain: FrozenSet = None
    f_range: FrozenSet = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.domain, self.f_range = (frozenset(x) for x in (self.f.keys(), self.f.values()))

    def image(self, a: A) -> B:
        ''' get the image of one item. '''
        return self.f[a]

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56350794
    def preimage(self, b: B) -> Set[A]:
        ''' get the preimage of one item. '''
        return set(a for a in self.f.keys() if self.f[a] == b)

    def image_(self, aa: Collection[A]) -> Set[B]:
        ''' get the image of a collection of items '''
        return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), [self.image(a) for a in aa])

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56350794
    def preimage_(self, bs: Collection[B]) -> Set[A]:
        ''' get the preimage of a collection of items '''
        return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), [self.preimage(b) for b in bs])
```

Comment: This is quite nice.  I wish there was a library for this sort of thing: concrete finite discrete math structures.  Basic things: finite sets, finite (partial) functions, finite binary relations, etc.... Perhaps I just need to dig around more.